# React Native crashing on launch after targeting Android API 33 (android 13)

Tags: android, react-native

Thanks in advance!

My React Native app seems to be crashing on launch only for Android 13.

I've attached the stacktrace from the Play Store below.

```
Exception com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException:
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
```

Our build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

We've tried googling for this stacktrace but cannot seem to find anything that corresponds to our problem.